# Nothing being returned to POST event after edit of record

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to edit a record. The Controller code is:

```
        public ActionResult EditFixture(int id)
    {
        RLSBCWebSiteDb _context = new RLSBCWebSiteDb();
        Fixture fixture = _context.Fixtures.Find( id );

        ViewData["Gender"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetGenderList(""), "Value", "Text", fixture.Gender );
        ViewData["MatchTypeList"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetMatchTypeList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.MatchType );
        ViewData["TeamNameList"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetTeamNameList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.TeamName );
        ViewData["CommentsList"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetCommentsList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.Comments );

        return View( fixture );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditFixture( Fixture fixture )
    {
        ViewData["Gender"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetGenderList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.Gender );
        ViewData["MatchTypeList"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetMatchTypeList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.MatchType );
        ViewData["TeamNameList"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetTeamNameList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.TeamName );
        ViewData["CommentsList"] = new SelectList( Fixture.GetCommentsList( "" ), "Value", "Text", fixture.Comments );

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            rlsbcWebSite.Fixtures.Add( fixture );
            rlsbcWebSite.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction( "DisplayFixtures", new { id = fixture.MatchDate.Year.ToString() } );
        }

        return View( fixture );
    }
```

The view code is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities.Fixture>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
UpdateFixture
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h1>Update the Fixture</h1>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fixture</legend>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FixtureID) %>
        <%: Html.Partial("CreateOrEditFixture") %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>

<div class="grid_2">
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    <br /><br />
</div>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptContent" runat="server"> </asp:Content>
```

The code for the partial is as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities.Fixture>" %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender) %>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Gender, (ViewData["GenderList"] as SelectList) ) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchType) %>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.MatchType, (ViewData["MatchTypeList"] as SelectList) )%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchType) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamName) %>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.TeamName, (ViewData["TeamNameList"] as SelectList) )%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamName) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchDate) %>
        <%: Html.TextBox( "MatchDate", Model.MatchDate.ToShortDateString() )%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchDate) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Opponents) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opponents) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Opponents) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Venue) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Venue) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Venue) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScoreFor) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScoreFor) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScoreFor) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScoreAgainst) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScoreAgainst) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScoreAgainst) %>

        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments) %>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Comments, (ViewData["CommentsList"] as SelectList) )%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments) %>
```

The `<div>`s have been removed in the above.

The call to edit the record displays the data OK including the correct choice for the dropdown lists. I make a few changes and the select the `Save` button. The correct POST event is called but the `Fixture fixture` parameter is null. ModelState is not valid and returns an error message of

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities.Fixture' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
```

Why is fixture of type Fixture not being passed back correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using editor templates:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fixture</legend>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FixtureID) %>
        <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

and inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Fixture.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities.Fixture>" 
%>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Gender, (ViewData["GenderList"] as SelectList) ) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchType) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.MatchType, (ViewData["MatchTypeList"] as SelectList) )%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchType) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamName) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.TeamName, (ViewData["TeamNameList"] as SelectList) )%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamName) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchDate) %>
<%: Html.TextBox( "MatchDate", Model.MatchDate.ToShortDateString() )%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchDate) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Opponents) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opponents) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Opponents) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Venue) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Venue) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Venue) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScoreFor) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScoreFor) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScoreFor) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScoreAgainst) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScoreAgainst) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScoreAgainst) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Comments, (ViewData["CommentsList"] as SelectList) )%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments) %>
```

A further improvement to this code would be to get rid of all `ViewData` and use strongly typed view models.

Comment: @Darin: How does it know which EditorTemplate to use if there is more than one in the folder? Is there some convention I have to follow. This particular view is enclosed in an Area. Does that make a difference where I store the template?

Comment: @xiecs, the convention is that the editor template must be in the `EditorTemplates` subfolder and have the same name as the type of your view model (`Fixture.ascx`). You also have the possibility to specify a name of the editor template either through the `[UIHint]` attribute or passing it as argument to the `EditorForModel` helper.

Comment: @Darin: I have changed it to the EditorTemplate and re-run it. It is still giving me the same conversion error message and ModelState is still not valid. The generated HTML for the form seems to be correct, as follows: `<form action="/MatchQuarter/Fixture/EditFixture/30?fixture=RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities.Fixture" method="post">`

Comment: @xiecs, your form action looks strange. Where is this `?fixture=xxx` query string parameter coming from? Do you have some custom routes? That's where the problem comes from, so the generated HTML is **not** correct.

Comment: @Darin: I assume it is picking it up from the `Inherits=` of the `Control` statement on the first line of the template or the `Page` statement on the view itself. That is what I am expecting `fixture` to be.

Comment: @xiecs, no, your Html.BeginForm helper is in the main view, not in the partial. It is this helper which is responsible for generating the form tag using the parameters you pass to it and the routes you have defined.

Comment: I would further wrap those three template calls in one extension method: `<%: Html.EditTemplateFor(model => model.Venue) %>`. This works bests when you have one template for your entire site, although you could use divs+classes with css to create different template styles.

Comment: @Darin: There is something more fundamentally wrong. If I take the code out of the Partial and include it in the View itself, it is still not returning anything to the POST event.

Comment: @Darin: Taking the `<form` statement from a few posts back, I think my problem is that `fixture=RLSBC...` is a querystring rather than the `id` part of the URL, which in this case is 30, and it is not being picked up by the POST event, and after scanning the web, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue too, I used Editor Templates also.
Try removing <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FixtureID) %>
Hidden fields passes string value, that is where I got the error. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. I fixed the problem some months ago but I have forgotten exactly what the fix was. I should have posted it at the time.